# Content Provider URI's hierarchical nature vs. Database's relational nature

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

Progressing with Android learning, I have been introduced to the concept of data source abstraction via a content provider.

I noticed that content providers are accessed via URIs, which are hierarchical in nature.

We all know about the limitations of hierarchy, which is *one* of the reasons relational databases are so much more prevalent.

The "problem" is that *hierarchical* URIs are aiming to represent *relational* databases.

Isn't this, in essence, reducing the power and flexibility of relational databases other access methods (e.g. SQL)? Something like "lossy compression"?

If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing may be that URI's define a piece of data, not all the relationships it has with other data.  They aren't representing the relational database, just a piece of data in that database.  You can think of the relational database as a bunch of overlapping hierarchies that give you many ways to get to the same piece of data.  A Uri just defines one of those paths.

I use a fairly complicated relational database, but I still can access a piece of data with a URI.

Here's my approach:

The Uri path is the data type (or database table for example) I want to retrieve data from.
The Uri Query parameters define the relationships that the data I want must satisfy.

You can use whatever query parameters you want and whatever data type you want to return.  It is then up to you how you implement that in your database manager.

Comment: I just discovered managedQuery() and it seems that you are correct. +1. The URI is only part of a query. The managedQuery() call, for example, takes additional parameters such as sort order, columns to be selected and a *where* clause. I am relieved. :)